# using flashzlib into flash project

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, alchemy

I am integrating [flashzlib](https://github.com/emcmanus/flashzlib) into one of my flash project. As mentioned in documentation of project. I have successfully generated libz.a and z.l.bc and pushed libs and headers in appropriate places.

Now, I have written this small wrapper https://gist.github.com/65d3c7ff683b326ecd22. This compiles just fine using:

```
gcc example1_as3.c -lz -O3 -Wall -swc -o example.swc
```

This is included into flash project like this (uncompressedData is a byteArray):

```
private var loader:CLibInit = new CLibInit;
private var lib:Object = loader.init();
logger.info("B : " + lib.returnString(uncompressedData, uncompressedData.length) + "");
```

But flash file **fails** at this last line. Am not sure what am i missing. z.l.bc file is 340KB while example.swc is just 80KB.

Comment: it logs nothing and no further code is executed. It just gets stuck here.

Comment: Quickly trying it myself, the runtime error I'm getting on `example.c:50` is `Undefined sym: _inflateInit_`.

Comment: @The_asMan no, just logger (logging.ILogger)

Comment: @Gunslinger47 how do you run it to see this error? I am running flash inside browser which doesn't throw anything at me :(

Comment: @Gunslinger47 also any hints how to fix this error? (may be some compile options?)

Comment: @Nakul Your example code works for me-- that is, it returns zero at the `// FAILS HERE` line. Does `logger.info("hello world")` show anything?  An ILogger doesn't send its output anywhere in particular unless it's told to, for example via [TraceTarget](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/logging/targets/TraceTarget.html)

Comment: @Gunslinger47 you'll get that runtime error if you don't have z.l.bc 'installed' in ALCHEMY_HOME/usr/local/lib.  Alternatively you can use -L in the gcc command.

Comment: I'm using Adobe Flash Builder's debugger.  To run your SWF directly without the need for a browser, you can go to your project properties under "ActionScript Compiler", then uncheck "Generate HTML wrapper file".

Comment: @paleozogt yes logger works just fine. i do get "hello world" :( but now am getting same error as Gunslinger47: "Undefined sym: _inflateInit_" though i compiled as you suggested :(

Comment: @paleozogt I am getting this error when running flash file and not while compiling :( what is size of your example.swc?

Comment: adding "-v" option to gcc command above, exits with error "ld: unknown option: -emit-llvm"

Comment: Why do you need zlib in Flash? What are you using it for?

Comment: @Cameron I am using it for speeding up inflate on ByteArray

Comment: @Nakul: Cool, but I thought that inflate was already pretty darn fast (especially compared to deflation)?

Comment: @Cameraon inflate means decompressing in actionscript, do you have some numbers? In my application I found decompression a culprit.

Comment: @Nakul: No numbers (so if you say it's the bottleneck I believe you), but generally it's compression that's slow, and decompression is fairly fast. LZ77-based compression (like zlib) is extremely fast to decompress in general (of course, there's also the Huffman coding which may be a little slower). The decompression algorithm is fairly straightforward; I'm a little surprised you can beat it with AVM2-based code (especially since I suspect Adobe uses zlib internally as a (compiled) C library).

Comment: @Cameron thanks for the info. Yesterday only, I found that Adobe inflate also uses native C code internally :(. Actually, I was comparing to java version of code which takes 1/4th the time in decompressing as compared to actionscript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

­It's failing for one of two reasons.  Either Alchemy isn't finding `z.l.bc` (and isn't bothering to tell you about it), or you're not catching and reporting your error codes correctly.

As I mentioned in the question comments, I was getting a runtime error on the `inflateInit` invocation.  For my case, it turned out that Alchemy wasn't searching `$ALCHEMY_HOME/usr/local/lib` for `z.l.bc` like it was supposed to be.  This was solved by moving it to `/usr/local/lib` instead.  After that, your code returned `Z_OK` as expected.

I notice you have all the `CHECK_ERR` calls commented out, which means that you'll enter an infinite loop if you comment out the early return on `example.c:52` since you're not checking for errors on your `inflate` call in the following unconditional `for` block.  For me, `inflate` was returning `Z_DATA_ERROR` since I was just handing it some UTF bytes for test purposes.

Speaking of testing, I notice that there's a small test suite supplied by flashzlib:

- https://github.com/emcmanus/flashzlib/blob/master/example.c

I borrowed this code, renamed `main` to `test_all`, commented out the call to `test_gzio`¹, and replaced all `printf` calls with `fprintf` calls to `stderr` instead².  This is the result:

```
zlib version 1.2.3 = 0x1230, compile flags = 0x2000095

uncompress(): hello, hello!

inflate(): hello, hello!

large_inflate(): OK

after inflateSync(): hello, hello!

inflate with dictionary: hello, hello! 

0
```

Everything appears to be in order.

footnotes:
¹ No file access in Alchemy, of course.
² `stdout` is disconnected for me, but `stderr` appears in my trace console

Comment: thanks @Gunslinger47. the flashzlib was working totally cool for me too. I tried pushing z.l.bc in /usr/local/lib but thats not working for me :(. will dig more and get back. thanks again!

Comment: ok, so am able to integrate it with command from Makefile i.e. gcc -O3 -DNO_vsnprintf -DUSE_MMAP -swc -o example.swc example1_as3.o -L. libz.a
Making it work now by passing right values. Thanks!